# How to disable iOS Shortcut ( Automation ) Programmatically?

Tags: ios, automation, shortcut

I have made an automation to open my app whenever a user opens Facebook app.
When the user taps on "Continue with Facebook" the automation which is forcing to open my App show be disabled for 2 minutes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I didn't understand well but you can set up a deep link in your app that activates a function of timer that disables the automation for 2 minutes when a user opens it

Comment: In iOS 14 and later, you can enable or disable automations directly from the Shortcuts app:
Open the Shortcuts app.
Tap the “Automation” tab at the bottom of the screen.
Select the automation you want to disable.
In the “Edit Automation” screen, toggle off the switch next to “Ask Before Running.”
Confirm your choice when prompted.
The automation won’t run automatically anymore.

Comment: OR

If you’ve created an automation to open your app whenever a user opens the Facebook app, and you want to disable it for a specific duration (e.g., 2 minutes) after the user taps “Continue with Facebook,” consider the following approach:
When the automation triggers, set a flag (e.g., a boolean variable) to indicate that your app should not open.
Implement a timer or delay mechanism (using DispatchQueue or similar) to enable the automation again after the specified duration (e.g., 2 minutes).
During this disabled period, your app won’t be forced to open by the automation.

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't provide enought details about how your shortcut works, i will suggest a general idea.
You can start a timer in your shortcut, which updates a variable whenever timer is running or not. If your variable says your timer is running, then skip your shortcut logic.